# How to add single option tag data to other HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html, web, tags

For example:

```
**index.html**
<body>
<option><select>1></select>
<select>2</select><select>3</select></option>
</body>
```

and having another file:

```
**page1.html**
<body>
here I want to have the same OPTION data
</body>
```

Is there any way to write the OPTION tag once, and then use it in multiple pages. I have to use them with up to 10 pages.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. See [option tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure its possible in javascript hoping that the option values are static and same for all pages.

In that case if you have a common javascript file (like helper.js,common.js)

Then you include that option code by dynamically binding to the body o your HTML
as Kenny mentioned correct you option tag format and check as how to dynamicaly append HTML using javascript

Functions to be used :
document.createElement()
document.body.insertBefore()

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.firstChild

Answer (score 0):

You can make a php file containing the "html tags".
Then you can include this php file in the required pages.

You can also use javascript.
Create an option.js file,
Use the HTML DOM functions like document.createElement() to create the option and select tags, document.createTextNode() to create a text element.

Then use the appendchild function to append the text node to option tags.

```
<script src="option.js"></script>
```

Use the above script tag in the pages where you require these options.
That is it!